# Polynomial time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

what could be a polynomial-time algorithm that finds [V / 2] vertices that collectively
account for at least three-fourths (3/4) of the edges in an arbitrary undirected
graph??

kindly help

Comment: The existence of such subset is not guaranteed ...

Comment: @belisarius do you have a counter-example? I think it is guaranteed to exist and is trivial to find, but it's possible there's an error in my logic.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but if you have a necklace type graph V/2 vertices account for 1/2 of the edges

Comment: @belisarius Taking either partition in a bipartite graph accounts for all of the edges. Since cycle graphs are either bipartite or one edge away from bipartite, we're only going to be missing out on one edge by taking V/2 alternating terms in the chain.

Comment: @Yonatan Thanks for your answer. My English comprehension is not always up to the task. At least I refrained from answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof that it exists:

Consider the algorithm that picks half of the vertices randomly. For any given edge, the probability that at least one of its two endpoints was chosen is 3/4, so the expected number of edges covered is 3|E|/4. Thus, by the [probabilistic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method), there must exist at least one covering of >= 3|E|/4 edges using just 1/2 of the vertices. The nondeterministic algorithm follows immediately.

Coming up with a *deterministic* algorithm based on this is an exercise in derandomization (try using [the method of conditional expectations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessimistic_estimator#The_method_of_conditional_probabilities_with_conditional_expectations)).

Comment: . I understand the probabilistic method. Could you explain deterministic algorithm more and with mathematically convincing proof. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Is there one? I suspect not but I honestly don't know; vertex cover is NP-complete and this is close (we're asking if `G` has a vertex cover of size at most `|V| / 2` that covers three-quarters of the edges.

Obviously try the greedy algorithm picking off vertices with the highest degree first.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, this doesn't make sense. I still think a greedy solution would work, though; if you keep picking vertices with at least an average degree, it seems to me that you'd get most of the total edges by the end. But I'm not sure about the proof.

Comment: I believe your interpretation of the vertex cover problem is backwards (either that or I'm misunderstanding you). The approximation algorithm gives you something with potentially twice as many vertices as necessary, not half (otherwise there would be a superoptimal solution!)

Comment: Hmm, use the greediest possible algorithm:  remove a vertex with the largest number of edges, along with those edges.  Repeat [V/2] times.